# Li tapping requires two clicks to fire href

Tags: jquery, html-lists, href, touchscreen

When clicking "Menu" with the mouse, the menu items are visible and I can click any of the links in the list with no problems.

When I use the tap gesture(touchscreen) on "Menu", the menu items become visible but...the items take 2 clicks to display the href and "Menu" becomes highlighted.

I know this might have something to do with propagation (or not) but I've tried the click event with jquery with no luck.  Also the hrefs are local files, so I don't want to navigate to them in the jquery click event.

```
$("#item1").click(function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
});


<li aria-haspopup="true"><span class="dir">Menu</span>
  <ul>
    <li id="#item1"><a href="../listItem1.html">listItem1</a></li>
    <li><a href="../listItem2.html">listItem2</a></li>
    <li><a href="../listItem3.html">listItem3</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the way the device works? What device is it? What happens if your links are not in `li`s? Same thing?

Comment: @DelightedD0D - Good questions.  The links outside the li do work when tapping on them.  Device is Surface RT.  IE11.

Comment: Have you tried a different browser at all? ... ie does weird crap

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```js
$("#group li").click(function(event) {
  alert('do stuf with click');
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li aria-haspopup="true" id="group"><span class="dir">Menu</span>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="../listItem1.html">listItem1</a></li>
    <li><a href="../listItem2.html">listItem2</a></li>
    <li><a href="../listItem3.html">listItem3</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```